# How do I add a comma in between JSON objects?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Say I have a sample.json file that looks like this. Notice the objects are not separated by a comma. I am aware that this is not a JSON file without the commas.

```
[
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HFHU5",
    "text": "hey there",
    "ts": "1385407681.000003"
  }
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HGJ4E",
    "text": "right back at you",
    "ts": "1385407706.000006"
  }
]
```

How do I make it look like this (example from I got the example from https://thoughtbot.com/blog/jq-is-sed-for-json.)

```
[
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HFHU5",
    "text": "hey there",
    "ts": "1385407681.000003"
  },
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HGJ4E",
    "text": "right back at you",
    "ts": "1385407706.000006"
  }
]
```

I tried doing },{ as some have suggested but it does not work.

I think it's probably something like this in jq on the command line but am not sure. Here, my hope is that sample2.json outputs the desired format.

```
jq -r '. | join(", ")' sample.json > sample2.json
```

Comment: Looking at the linked blog article it seems to be a typo : `1.json` as described in the article contains a comma. Without it it's neither valid JSON nor a sequence of valid JSON and you'd need to manipulate it as text before feeding it to `jq`. For instance `sed '1d;$d'` would remove the first and last line which would be enough to make the input a sequence of valid JSON objects

Comment: (for clarity, the complete pipeline would look like this : `sed '1d;$d' sample.json | jq -s '.' > sample2.json`)

Comment: "I tried doing },{ [...] but it does not work" – then you did it wrong. If you show excatly what you did, we could probably tell you why. (And how to fix.)

Answer (score 3):

Using [human JSON utility](https://hjson.github.io/) to recover your malformed JSON file:

```
hjson -j file
[
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HFHU5",
    "text": "hey there",
    "ts": "1385407681.000003"
  },
  {
    "type": "message",
    "user": "U024HGJ4E",
    "text": "right back at you",
    "ts": "1385407706.000006"
  }
]
```

The option `-j` outputs the file with correct JSON syntax, by adding the missing comma between objects.

Comment: How could I pipe the jq output into hjson so I can do a one line command

Comment: @JRobz Unless I don't understand your question, there is no point to pipe the output of `jq` into `hjson` since `jq` outputs correct json.

Comment: Well that wasn't the case for me, the output did not include comments for whatever reason. perhaps I didn't use the correct settings for jq. I did figure it out though.

Answer (score 2):

If the square brackets were not in the input, `jq` could process it like normal as a stream of objects. You could then throw them into an array or whatever.

You'll just need to invoke jq twice in this case. First read it in raw (`-Rs`) and trim out the leading and trailing brackets, output it raw (`-r`), then process in jq like normal.

```
$ jq -Rsr 'gsub("^\\s*\\[|\\]\\s*$"; "")' input.json | jq -n '[inputs]'
```